# Export files for xcopy installation of ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation, build-process

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that I'd like to install somewhere using xcopy (as opposed to an installer).

How do I export/build to a folder that I can copy straight to the IIS environment?  I think at work we use a web deployment project but that's a plugin and I was wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, you can right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose "Publish". This will allow you to publish directly to IIS, via FTP and via FPSE.

For your purposes, though, you can choose the Filesystem option and point it somewhere local. There should be everything you need in that directory to do XCOPY deployment.

Comment: Any idea how you automate this in a build script?